# jQuery help needed with hover

Tags: jquery, hover

Hey guys for some strange reason I can't get this to work...I just need a simple effect on hover where if the link is hovered upon, the padding-left changes to a certain pixels..

```
jQuery("nav li ul li").hover(function() {
     var padding = parseInt(jQuery(this).find("> a").css("paddingLeft");
         var new_padding = (padding + 5);   
     jQuery(this).find("> a").stop(true,true).animate({ paddingLeft: new_padding},200);
     }, function() { jQuery(this).find("> a").animate({ paddingLeft: padding},200);}
);
```

So the above I am just trying to say move the padding left to 5 more than the original and move it back to original when mouse out. The above keeps moving to the right with padding and doesn't go back for some reason...I know I am missing something simple..

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strong suggest you use += and -= animation capabilities in jQuery to add and remove a fixed amount from the padding.  That way you can do everything a lot simpler without actually fetching the value of the padding or having to keep track of anything in variables.  See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for examples.  Using this will also solve the scoping problem you have with the new_padding variable because you won't need it any more.

Then, I don't think the find("> a") is necessarily doing what you want.  If you just want to find "a" tags that are children of the nav li ul li that is being hovered over, then you should just do find("a").  That will find descendants of all the matches selectors in the first call that are "a" tags.

I think you can use something like this:

```
jQuery("nav li ul li").hover(
     function() {
         jQuery(this).find("a").stop(true,true).animate({paddingLeft: "+=5"},200);
     }, 
     function() { 
         jQuery(this).find("a").stop(true, true).animate({paddingLeft: "-=5"},200);
     }
);
```

You can see it work here in this demo of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9YQaV/

Comment: I added a jsFiddle demo you can see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

Without running your code, I'm going to guess that the second function is throwing an error, and never getting executed.  You've defined `padding` as a local variable in the *first* function, but the second function doesn't know about it.  It looks for `padding` in its scope, doesn't find it, looks for it at the global scope, doesn't find it, and throws an exception.

Fire up [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) in Firefox to see if I'm right...  If I am, you've got a couple options:

1. Make `padding` a global.  You should be able to do this just by removing the `var` part of its declaration.  But globals are kinda sketchy, and they'll rely on the functions that rely on them being called in the expected order (in1 -> out1 -> in2 -> etc.), and while that's likely, it's not guaranteed.
2. Reload the `margin` property from the element in each function.  This is what I'd do, even if it's a touch less efficient.

(Breaker line to force SO to format this...)

```
$("nav li ul li").hover(
    function() {$(this).find("> a").animate({ paddingLeft: load_padding() + 5}, 200);},
    function() {$(this).find("> a").animate({ paddingLeft: load_padding() - 5}, 200);}
)
```

Hope this helps!

**PS:**  Hopefully that code formats okay - this preview's butchering it...

**PPS:** It didn't, but I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're missing a closing parenthesis here:

```
var padding = parseInt(jQuery(this).find("> a").css("paddingLeft");
```

and you should **always** supply the `radix` argument to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var padding = parseInt(jQuery(this).find("> a").css("paddingLeft"), 10);
```

Then you have a scope issue with `padding`. You're declaring `padding` in the first function argument to `hover` but trying to use it in both the first and second functions; the result is that the `animate` in the mouseout function does nothing because `padding` isn't defined in there.

If you put your `var padding;` outside the hover functions:

```
var padding;
jQuery("nav li ul li").hover( //...
```

You'll get better results.